# Prove $\sum_{i = 0}^{n} { (3 i+1)^2}$ is $(n+1) (6 n^2+9 n+2)/2$?

Tags: real-analysis, summation

I am stuck on what kind of process to use to go about solving this problem:

Prove that $\sum_{i = 0}^{n} { (3 i+1)^2}=(n+1) (6 n^2+9 n+2)/2$

Any advice would be great!

Thanks so much!

Comment: I have changed your statement as you had $n$ appearing both inside and outside the sum when you said "Prove sum (3 n+1)^2 from 0 to n = 1/2 (n+1) (6 n^2+9 n+2)"

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Use induction, noting that the formula holds for $n = 0$

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{k=0}^n (3k+1)^2=\sum_{k=0}^n(9k^2+6k+1)=\sum_{k=0}^n9k^2+\sum_{k=0}^n 6k +\sum_{k=0}^n 1\\=9\left[\sum_{k=0}^nk^2\right]+6\left[\sum_{k=0}^nk\right]+\sum_{k=0}^n1\\$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The sum $\sum_{i=1}^n i= (n+1)n/2$, and the sum $\sum_{i=1}^n i^2 = n(n+1)(2n+1)/6$, so if you assume this knowledge you can show your formula.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much! I'll give this a shot.